# setContentView() giving error in onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android

I am working on a problem to fix Activity restart on screen rotation, I am implementing [the 2nd part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/456918/2715065), it gives me the error in `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_introduction)`.

> The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type IntroductionFragment.

```
public class IntroductionFragment extends Fragment {

public IntroductionFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction,container,false);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_introduction);
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.indianconstitution"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

How to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no `setContentView()` in `Fragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onConfigurationChanged()` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction, null);
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getView();
    rootView.removeAllViews();
    rootView.addView(view);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help ! App is restarted after orientation changed :(

Comment: apologies for the mistake ... does it work correctly after the edit ??

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView` is a method of `Activity`. You are inside a `Fragment`. The View hierarchy for the fragment is build upon the return value of `onCreateView`